# Is a request for a list of anime with a specific kind of eye, reasonably scoped?

Tags: discussion

Is a request for a list of anime with a specific kind of eye, reasonably scoped?

I ask, because I want to find Anime that have eyes like these, where the eye is two complete ovals inside each other where the inner oval is a darker shade of the color of the outer oval, with some white border, and a dot of light inside the larger oval:

[image: EasyGameStation Eyes?]

Answer (score 10):

**No**, this does not seem reasonably scoped to me. There will be likely hundreds of anime and related media containing this kind of style.

*Even if* the number of anime featuring this style is only 2 or 3, in reality the person answering it would legitimately have to be aware of the art style in thousands of anime to be able to answer it.

Comment: To add to the point here - even if we does allow it with community wiki + wiki lock, the question will be useless without people updating it. The way SE works doesn't give enough exposure of the question and incentive for people to add the content to a community wiki.